Dropdown menu has no background so page text shows through, how do I put a box behind the dropdown menu?
I made a nav bar and there's a dropdown menu. I need to find a way to put a box in behind the dropdown menu because everything shows underneath when you're trying to read the menu. This is the html that I have so far. I haven't linked anything yet but visually it works.
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Aclonica, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 30px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #B598F9;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #B598F9;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content .header {
  background: #B598F9;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #B598F9;
  height: 100px;
}

.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover {
  background-color: #B598F9;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
    .center {margin:auto;
    width: 50%;}






`<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">      <img src="images/lotus_painting.png" 
                        type="images/lotus_painting.png" 
                        rel="icon" height="75px" width="75px"></a>
  <a href="#">Artists <br>Hour</a>
  <!--This is the page list of artists-->
  
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" style="font-size:30px">School <br>of Art 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Where Would You Like To Go?</h1>
      </div>   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h1>Art Study</h1>
          <a href="#">Fundamentals</a>
          <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h1>How To...</h1>
          <a href="#">Upgrade Your <br>Art Business</a>
          <a href="#">Have A Good <br>Portfolio</a>
          <a href="#">Achieve <br>Multi-Stream<br> Income</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h1>Business</h1>
          <a href="#">Tax Facts</a>
          <a href="#">Terms of Service<br> Checklist</a>
          <a href="#">How To Be<br> Prepared To <br> Talk To A <br>Lawyer</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

I've tried creating boxes behind each one (the long way I know) but it looks like sh*t. I was hoping to find a way to get the whole area beyond "Where would you like to go?" to have it's own box but I feel like I'm missing a good chunk of code to make this happen. Lost and new at this...

I found an answer through playing with all the code
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #B598F9;
  height: 400px;
}

The height just needed adjusted to encapsulate it all.
